# Get position of first occurrence of class (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I detect the position of a section, which is the first section with a specific class?

For instance I have four sections:

- The first section has the class `banana`
- the second section class `apple`
- the third also `apple`
- the last `orange`.

How can I detect the position of the first occurrence of apple — which would be position 2?

Comment: You are going to have to set up your own system for storing the section structure. We can certainly find any particular element you want to find, but mapping that to a number based on your DOM structure will require you setting that up somehow. Can you alter the HTML to add a `data-number` attribute and plant the appropriate numbers in that attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `index()` method to achieve this, if you provide it a selector to group by. Try this:

```js
var appleIndex = $('.apple').index('.section');
console.log(appleIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section banana">Banana</div>
<div class="section apple">Apple</div>
<div class="section melon">Melon</div>
<div class="section grape">Grape</div>
```

Note that the index is zero-based, so the second item would be index `1`, not `2` as in your question. You can easily add 1 to it if require, though.

Comment: Nice answer, you may want to adjust the output by 1 to meet the OP requirements.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There's a note about it just under the snippet. Personally I'd work with the index as it is, unless it needs to be shown in the UI.

Comment: Agreed. Didn't see your note.

Comment: Thank you very much for your good illustration. You really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a jQuery plugin to iterate over the elements and retrieve their position.

The following function is a jQuery plugin to iterate over some elements and check if it has a particular class. If it has it, its position will be returned.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.idiciesOfClass = function(className) {
    return this.map(function(index) {
      return $(this).hasClass(className) ? index : -1;
    }).toArray().filter(function(pos) {
      return pos > -1;
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

#### Demo

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.idiciesOfClass = function(c) {
    return this.map((i, e) => $(e).hasClass(c) ? i : -1).toArray().filter(x => x > -1);
  }
})(jQuery);

console.log('Apple class indicies:', $('.section').idiciesOfClass('apple').join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section banana">Banana</div>
<div class="section apple">Apple</div>
<div class="section apple">Apple</div>
<div class="section orange">Orange</div>
```

> Apple class indicies: 1, 2

Answer (score 0):

If they are all located within a `id='parent'` object, then you can do it like so:

```
$('#parent').children().each(function (i, v) {
    if ($(v).hasClass("apple"))
    {
        console.log(i);
        return false;
    }
});
```